# Rearranging an array odds and evens using recursive method

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting, data-structures

Here I am trying to reorder an array of int elements like this: 2 4 6 8 1 3 5 7 9.

I tried the code below but it's not working. It prints them the same as 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9.
I need help in understanding the process of reordering this array as evens in left and odds in the right order.

```
 static void Orgnaize(int[] data) {
     /* Initialize left and right indexes */
        int left = 0, right = data.length - 1; 
        
        for(int i =0;left < right; i++) 
        { 
            /* Increment left index while we see 0 at left */
            for(int j =0; data[left]%2 == 0 && left < right; j++) 
                left++; 
  
            /* Decrement right index while we see 1 at right */
            for (int k =0;data[right]%2 == 1 && left < right;k--) 
                right--; 
  
            if (data[left] %1 ==0) 
            { 
                /* Swap arr[left] and arr[right]*/
                int temp = data[left]; 
                data[left] = data[right]; 
                data[right] = temp; 
                left++; 
                right--; 
                Orgnaize(data); 
            } 
        } 
     }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you try this, https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sort-even-numbers-ascending-order-sort-odd-numbers-descending-order/

Comment: Make all even integers negative and sort them. Make all positive again.

Comment: It won't work bro, as that would make, 8 6 4 2 1 3 5 7 9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
static void Orgnaize(int[] data, int left, int right) {
    if(left >= right) {
        return;
    }

    if(data[left] % 2 == 0 && data[right] % 2 == 1) {
        // both pointers are fine so move both
        Orgnaize(data, left + 1, right - 1);
    }
    else if(data[right] % 2 == 1) {
        // if right is odd then right one is fine
        Orgnaize(data, left, right-1);
    }
    else if(data[left] % 2 == 1) {
        // right is even which is not correct(since we checked just before) and
        // left is odd which is wrong too
        // so swap
        int temp = data[left];
        data[left] = data[right];
        data[right] = temp;
        Orgnaize(data, left + 1, right - 1);
    }
    else {
        // only case remaining
        // right is even(wrong) and left is even(fine)
        // so move left
        Orgnaize(data, left + 1, right);
    }
}
```

call this function by `Orgnaize(arr, 0, arr.length - 1)`

Comment: How to test it in a main method ?

Comment: call Orgnaize(arr, 0, arr.length - 1)

Comment: Welcome. I am glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a small issue in your value swap logic... it should be

```
int temp = arr[first];
arr[first] = arr[last];
arr[last] = temp;
```

Comment: How to test it in the main method?

Answer (score 0):

Probably there would be more optimized solution - but as of now this one is able to reorder *1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13* to *2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13* ... call it by organize(arr, 0);

```
    static void organize(int[] arr, int first) {
    if ((first + 1) < (arr.length - 1)) {
        if (arr[first] % 2 == 1) {
            int second = first + 1;
            boolean evenFound = false;
            if (arr[second] % 2 != 0) {
                for (int i = (second + 1); i < (arr.length - 1); i++) {
                    if (arr[i] % 2 == 0) {
                        second = i;
                        evenFound = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                for (int i = second; i > first && evenFound; i--) {
                    int temp = arr[i];
                    arr[i] = arr[i - 1];
                    arr[i - 1] = temp;
                }
            } else {
                int temp = arr[first];
                arr[first] = arr[second];
                arr[second] = temp;
            }
        }
            organize(arr, first + 1);
    }
}
```